# Sending data using ajax to the controller in rails

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and rails so recently facing lots of difficulties about using ajax in rails environment. I will very appreciate if you contribute to developing my project.  What I am trying to do is that Once a user selects data from the modal, I want to send the selected data to an action in the controller so that I can handle the data. I am not really sure where I can start with that. Please help guys :( Thanks a lot

view:

```
 <form id= "selected_form" action="" method="">
      <div id= "selected_form">
        <p id="checkids"></p>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <div>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Select Task</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <fieldset>
                <% @tasks.each do |task|%>
                  <div>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="<%=task.id%>" name="selected"><%=task.title%></label>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(){
      var checkedItem = [];
      $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function(){
        checkedItem.push($(this).val());
      });
      $('#values').html("selected values are: " + checkedItem.join(", "));
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // request method for your action like get,post,put,delete
        url: "/users/<%= current_user.id %>/test", // route of your rails action
        data: {checked_items: checkedItem.join(", ")}, // attach data here you will get this data in your controller action with params[:checked_items]
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){}, // do whatever you want when it success
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}
      })
    });

    });

  });
      </script>
```

Comment: Why are you creating input fields and submit button using plain HTML tags, and not `rails`? You don't need to write custom Ajax if you have the `name` attribute set correctly on the checkboxes. You can just submit with `remote: true` and it will be a JS request to your controller action.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not very good at this and quite confused with how to do. Can you give me more specific examples?

Comment: You can checkout [form_helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) and [`remote: true`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-ajax). It's not out of the world. Pretty easy to implement. Give it a try and we are here to help if you are stuck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check script below

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#save").click(function(){
      var checkedItem = [];
      $.each($("input[name='selected']:checked"), function(){
        checkedItem.push($(this).val());
      });
      $('#values').html("selected values are: " + checkedItem.join(", "));
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", // request method for your action like get,post,put,delete
        url: "/things", // route of your rails action
        data: {checked_items: checkedItem }, // attach data here you will get this data in your controller action with params[:checked_items]
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...}, // do whatever you want when it success
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){...}
      })
    });

    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: you should get in this params[:checkedItem]. but if you don't get in this param, check the log of server. try to debug your action before finding task. let me know if its still unclear to you

Comment: remove the `join(", ")` from js script, because it joins the different element with `,` so you get in that format

Comment: That works like what I want! thanks a lot, can I quickly ask you another question? If I want to keep the check values. For example, if a user selected 3 inputs, can I keep the 3 inputs are selected? even though the page is reloaded. Do I need to use localstorage ? if it is, can you please tell me how..?

Comment: Yes, you can use local storage for it. :)

Comment: could you please update some basic ideas of how to do the localstorage stuff? if it is not too complicate?

Comment: You can ask new question for that

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity you can inject rails path to that controller as dataset attribute.
for e.g

```
<form method="post" data-url="<%= tasks_path %>">
```

and in js part

```
  $('#save').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).method || "GET",
      url: this.dataset.url,
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: It should be on submit event. not on click